# Is there any plan to implement complex survey design within Spark's MLLIB package?

Tags: pyspark, sas, apache-spark-mllib, survey

I'm working to implement a logistic regression in Pyspark that is currently written in SAS using `proc surveylogistic`. The SAS implementation is able to account for complex survey design involving clusters/strata/sample weights.

There are some avenues out there for at least getting the model into Python: for example, I was able to get a close match of both coefficients and standard errors using the `statsmodels` package from [this research project on Github](https://github.com/jarvmiller/statsmodels/tree/master/statsmodels/survey)

However, my data is big and so I'd like to take advantage of Spark's distributed capabilities through the MLLIB package. For example, the current setup to run the logit in Spark is:

```
import pyspark.ml.feature as ft
featuresCreator = ft.VectorAssembler(
                  inputCols = X_features_list,
                  outputCol = "features")

glm_binomial = GeneralizedLinearRegression(family="binomial", link="logit",  maxIter=25, regParam = 0,                                   
    labelCol='df',
    weightCol='wgt_panel')

from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[featuresCreator, glm_binomial])
model = pipeline.fit(encoded_df_nonan)
```

The "weightcol" works for just simple sample weights, but I'm wondering if anyone is aware of a method for implementing a more complex weighting scheme in Spark (note that the above would match a proc logistic, not a proc surveylogistic). For comparison, the method used to calculate the covariance matrix in the surveylogistic is [here](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_surveylogistic_a0000000364.htm).